# Using a <textarea> to populate a hidden value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a `<textarea>` that is outside of a form. This form has a hidden value called `uadc` which should be filled with the contents in the `<textarea>` when the form is submitted. How would I pass the value like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function() {
    $('#uadc').val( $('#yourTextarea').val() );
});
```